# Question based on exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function

I need a little bit of help in the following exercise:

If $a^x=b^y=c^z$ and $b^2=ac$, then prove that $y=\frac{2xz}{x+z}$.

Comment: This is not true. Counterexample: we have $(-1)^2 = 1^1 = (-1)^2$ and $1^2=(-1)(-1)$ but $1\ne\frac{2(2)(2)}{2+2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$a^x=b^y=c^z=k$$

$$a=k^{\frac 1x}$$

$$b=k^{\frac 1y}$$

$$c=k^{\frac 1z}$$

Now given, $$b^2=ac$$

$$\left(k^{\frac 1y}\right)^2 = k^{\frac 1x} \cdot k^{\frac 1z}$$

$$k^{\frac 2y} = k^{\frac 1x + \frac 1z}$$

$$\frac 2y = \frac 1x + \frac 1z$$

$$\frac 2y = \frac {z+x}{xz}$$

Reciprocating both sides,

$$\frac y2 = \frac {xz}{x+z}$$

$$y = \frac {2xz}{x+z}$$

Answer (score 0):

from the given system we get
$$a=e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{x}}$$ and so on thus we have
$$e^{\frac{2\ln(t)}{y}}=e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{x}}\cdot e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{z}}$$
since $$t\ne 1$$
we get
$$\frac{2}{y}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{x}$$
p.s.: $t=a^x$ and so on